# onMeasure with wrap_content is taking parameters that are not Integer.MIN_VALUE

Tags: android, android-layout

In my xml I specified wrap_content for both the width and height but when I override the onMeasure function the width and height that are passed to it is -2147483348 which oddly is 300 > Integer.MIN_VALUE is there a reason for this? why is it not integer.MIN_VALUE or 0 if I didn't have anything inside it. BTW this is a custom view that i'm making so I have to do setMeasuredDimension I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments to `onMeasure` are not the available width and height, but an encoding of the available width and height along with flags about how those values are supposed to be used. You decode them using the [`View.MeasureSpec`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.MeasureSpec.html) class:

```
protected void onMeasure(int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
    final int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthSpec);
    final int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthSpec);
    // etc.
}
```

The mode will be one of `AT_MOST`, `EXACTLY`, or `UNSPECIFIED`. See the docs for how you are supposed to use this. In particular, if the mode is not `UNSPECIFIED` you *must not* use a value greater than the size for that dimension when you call `setMeasuredDimension`.

Comment: Thanks, I should of looked for the documentation